# Assign score value to a number that is in a range with java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm using optaplanner library and I'm trying to provided it with a score.
I got everything running where I'm trying to balance 2000 mailbox objects among 30 databases objects (bin packing).

optaplanner is moving the mailboxes between databases based on score that is calculated based on the mailbox size and how much space it occupies in the database.

I figured that the most optimal approach to a score would be find out how much space is used up in the database and if it between 200GB to 220GB raise the score by 1. If it is above or bellow subtract by 1.

BUT after watching the debug go I have seen that I will need to be more granular probably down to a 1GB.

I'm facing a problem of a lot of if statements or possibly switch (but probably not since I would need to use final static variable)

### Question is:

Is there pattern or library that could do the scoring based on ranges for me?

Here is relevant piece of my code:

```
public HardSoftScore calculateScore(MailboxToDatabase mailboxToDatabase) {
    int hardScore = 0;
    int softScore = 0;

    int l0 = 229001;
    int u0 = 10000000;

    int l1 = 180001;
    int u1 = 229000;

    int l2 = 150001;
    int u2 = 180000;

    int l3 = 140001;
    int u3 = 150000;

    int l4 = 130001;
    int u4 = 140000;

    int l5 = 120001;
    int u5 = 130000;

    int l6 = 100001;
    int u6 = 120000;


    int loweUsers = 66;
    int highUsers = 71;

    List<Database> dl = mailboxToDatabase.getDatabaseList();

    // Hard constraints
    // Check each database for size
    for (Database d : dl) {
        //System.out.println(d.getName()+" USED: "+d.getTakenSpace()+" MB: "+d.getMailboxCount() );

        int value = d.getTakenSpace();
        int users = d.getMailboxCount();
        if (l0 <= value && value <= u0) {
            hardScore = hardScore-5;
        }
        if (l1 <= value && value <= u1) {
            hardScore = hardScore+1;
        }
        if (l2 <= value && value <= u2) {
            hardScore = hardScore-1;
        }
        if (l3 <= value && value <= u3) {
            hardScore = hardScore-2;
        }
        if (l4 <= value && value <= u4) {
            hardScore = hardScore-3;
        }
        if (l5 <= value && value <= u5) {
            hardScore = hardScore-4;
        }
        if (l6 <= value && value <= 0) {
            hardScore = hardScore-5;
        }
        if (loweUsers <= users && users <= highUsers)
            softScore++;
    }

    return HardSoftScore.valueOf(hardScore, softScore);
}
```

Comment: Why not define a helper class to encapsulate your limits and score delta, stick a bunch in an array, and then just loop?

Comment: Could you point me to an example? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any library that would do what you asked. But you could speed up you code considerably with some changes:

a) Don't check the interval. Check only the left limit:

Instead of

```
    if (l0 <= value && value <= u0) {
        hardScore = hardScore-5;
    }
```

Do

```
    if (value > MAX_LIMIT) {
        // error condition here
        return;
    }
    if (l0 <= value) { // no need to check the upper limit because it was already handled by the if above
        hardScore = hardScore-5;
    }
```

b) Speed up your code using elses and avoid checking the value 7 times:

Instead of

```
    if (l2 <= value && value <= u2) {
        hardScore = hardScore-1;
    }
    if (l3 <= value && value <= u3) {
        hardScore = hardScore-2;
    }
```

Have

```
    if (l2 <= value) {
        hardScore = hardScore-1;
    }
    else if (l3 <= value) {
        hardScore = hardScore-2;
    }
```